# Rails controller specific assets for selected controllers only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I want to use the controller specific assets only for some controllers, but not for all. Hence, I didn't add the assets for which I don't need separate files. But this leads to 404 for those resources as they are not present, e.g. my `app/views/layouts/dashboard.html.erb` file contains the following piece of code to generate the controller specific js/css:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'dashboard', params[:controller], media: 'all' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'dashboard', params[:controller] %>
```

However, I do not want to create separate files for Admin controller, as the admins page has no new css/js required. But, app tries to locate the assets for the controller and since not found it returns the 404 as follows:

```
GET http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/stylesheets/dashboard/admins.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/javascripts/dashboard/admins.js 404 (Not Found)
```

What should be done to prevent this?

Moreover, there are a few controllers for which the assets are obviously not required, e.g. Registrations controller, leading to 404 for `http://0.0.0.0:3000/stylesheets/store/registrations.css` for `http://0.0.0.0:3000/account/edit` page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix this in my application.html.erb:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'dashboard' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] if InmonarchWebsite::Application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.css") %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'dashboard' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if InmonarchWebsite::Application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.js") %>
```

Comment: You can also just use `rescue nil` instead of checking to see if the asset exists.